# Android x86 Image emulator does not launch without HAX (SDK Tools v.23)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Since i've updated to Android SDK Tools v.23, the AVD manager isn't allowing me to launch the emulator.

"emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing)."

My laptop does not support virtualisation. However, till v.22 for Android SDK tools, my emulator worked fine(it wasn't very fast because there wasn't HAX installed, however it was still better than ARM images).
So what can i do now to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use HAX images on non-Intel processors and on Intel processors which don't support hardware virtualization. As per [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows):

**System Requirements**

*Hardware Requirements:*

- Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel®
  64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
- At least 1 GB of available RAM

***Important***: Intel HAXM cannot be used on systems without an Intel processor, or with an Intel processor that lacks the hardware features described in the "Hardware Requirements" section above.
To determine the capabilities of your Intel processor, visit http://ark.intel.com/
Additionally, Intel HAXM can be used only with Android x86 emulator images provided by Intel. 
Intel HAXM cannot be used with ARM Android emulator images or non-Intel x86 Android emulator images.